# Analysis of a sample with several Na compounds

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I have a sample that is composed of NaOH, NaNO3 and NaCl in unknown proportions and I would like to determine the approximate proportions. I can determine the melting point of the combination.

I was thinking that I could determine the NaOH percentage by using a pH meter and making an aqueous solution - finding the amount of pure NaOH that it would take to get the same pH in the same volume  of water. My assumption is that the other two components won't affect pH.

That still leaves the other two. I could fiddle with the percentages until the melting point is matched, but is there an easier way that is not too expensive and requires only limited equipment and knowledge?

Comment: A simple titration with standard acid will measure NaOH or the pH. A Mohr titration [or potentiometric since you have a pH meter] with silver nitrate will determine chloride. The nitrate makes up the difference or you can buy a nitrate test kit.  More sophisticated methods would be ion chromatography or ir or Raman analysis to  determine nitrate. I like the two titrations and a Hach test kit. If you have a differential scanning calorimeter the mp test might work.

Comment: @jimchmst Thanks. The silver nitrate approach seems simple enough. That looks a lot like an answer...